# Error subsetting a data frame in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am learning python and pandas and am having trouble overcoming an error while trying to subset a data frame.

I have an input data frame:

```
df0-
    Index   Group   Value
    1       A       10
    2       A       15
    3       B       20
    4       C       10
    5       C       10

    df0.dtypes-
    Group   object
    Value   float64
```

That I am trying to split out into unique values based off of the `Group` column. With the output looking something like this:

```
df1-
Index   Group   Value
1       A       10
2       A       15

df2-
Index   Group   Value
3       B       20

df3-
Index   Group   Value
4       C       10
5       C       10
```

So far I have written this code to subset the input:

```
UniqueGroups = df0['Group'].unique().tolist()
OutputFrame = {}
for x in UniqueAgencies:          
    ReturnFrame[str('ConsolidateReport_')+x] = UniqueAgencies[df0['Group']==x]
```

The code above returns the following error, which I can`t quite work my head around. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

```
*** TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use groupby to group the column

```
for _, g in df0.groupby('Group'):
  print g
```